Why VS Code cannot detect IR kernel? Cannot run R jupyter notebook in VS Code
I've gone through
`install.packages('IRkernel')
IRkernel::installspec(user = TRUE) 

many times, and I can find IR kernel using jupyter kernelspec list.
The thing is, VS Code cannot detect the kernel linked with IR. And it always tries to treat R jupyter notebook with R scripts. So I got this error every time:
Error: unexpected '[' in:
"{
 "cells": ["
Execution halted

Very frustrating and I totally cannot understand the reason. I can run the R jupyter notebook in a web browser without any problem. But I don't want to run my code in a web browser and I prefer VS Code.
Any help is appreciated!
I cannot run R jupyter notebook in VS Code.
